# Where is the Baldurs Gate save file located?

Tags: baldurs-gate

I want to switch the game save file to another computer, but can't find them in the install folder, where are they?

Comment: What Windows version are you talking about? Is this the GoodOldGames version of the game?

Comment: My Documents/Games (at least that's where I would lok for in the first place, assuming you're using windows 7)?

Comment: My Windows version is Windows 7, and the game is not of GoodOldGames version, there's a folder named "save" in install folder, but my save file isn't in it.

Answer (score 5):

I've found it, its in

> C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Baldur's Gate\